# Creating metadata using \hypersetup

Tags: metadata

I'm trying to create metadata using `\hypersetup` but it doesn't work. Here are the commands I use

```
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={title},    % title
    pdfauthor={Salvatore Mazzarino},     % author
    pdfsubject={Subject},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Salvatore Mazzarino},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Salvatore Mazzarino}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={Green Networking} {Mobile Cloud} {Network Coding} {Energy}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=false,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=red,          % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor)
    citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=cyan           % color of external links
}
```

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: You can't set the metadata with `\hypersetup` when `pdfx` is used.

Comment: See also question of same user: [Add metadata in pdf as type pdf/a](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87912/add-metadata-in-pdf-as-type-pdf-a).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The documentation of `pdfx` is pretty clear on how metadata should be inserted, see Section 2.1:

> As mentioned above, standards compliant PDF documents need XMP metadata to be included. In order to create XMP in the prescribed XML format, a simple data file holding the meta information of the document needs to be created either through a program or by hand. For our purposes, we name it as `\jobname.xmpdata`, a simple example of which will look like the following:
>
> ```
>     \Keywords{pdfTeX\sep PDF/X-1a\sep PDF/A-b}
>     \Title{Sample LaTeX input file}
>     \Author{LaTeX project team}
>     \Org{TeX Users Group}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

When the wish is to create metadata using `\hypersetup` then don't use `pdfx` because it's approach is to use a separate .xmpdata file. This approach is incompatible with the hypersetup metadata commands.

See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/535849/50129) for a minimal example that uses `\hypersetup` and `hyperxmp`.

Also `pdfcreator` and `pdfproducer` should not be set. They declare which TeX engine was used not the author of the PDF. `pdfpublisher` may be what you' re looking for.