# Add metadata in pdf as type pdf/a

Tags: pdf, metadata, pdf-a

I have created using pdfx a pdf using this command:

```
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
```

I would add metadata but I don't really understand how do it.

I read the doc  but I didn't understand

[pdfx guide](http://ftp.uniroma2.it/TeX/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/pdfx.pdf)

Comment: My preamble is too long... and I have a lot of input

Comment: Why duplicate questions?

Comment: what questions duplicate?

Comment: This one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87909/creating-metadata-using-hypersetup

Comment: is it different...there I'm asking how insert metadata using hypersetup...here I'm asking how insert data using pdfx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From `pdfx` manual:

> 2.1. Data file for XMP metadata
>
> As mentioned above, standards compliant PDF documents need XMP
>   metadata to be included. In order to create XMP in the prescribed XML
>   format, a simple data file holding the meta information of the
>   document needs to be created either through a program or by hand. For
>   our purposes, we name it as \jobname.xmpdata, a simple example of
>   which will look like the following:
>
> ```
>   \Keywords{pdfTeX\sep PDF/X-1a\sep PDF/A-b} 
>   \Title{Sample LaTeX input file} 
>   \Author{LaTeX project team}
>   \Org{TeX Users Group}
> ```

So you have to put the xmpdata in a separate file. We can do it using `filecontents`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xmpdata}
\Keywords{pdfTeX\sep PDF/X-1a\sep PDF/A-b} 
\Title{Sample LaTeX input file} 
\Author{LaTeX project team} 
\Org{TeX Users Group}
\Doi{123456789} 
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

To compile this you may have to download the ICC profile (`ISOcoated_v2_300_bas.ICC`) from here:  [Color management ISO profile](http://www.colormanagement.org/en/isoprofile.html). Simply rename the downloaded file as `FOGRA39L.ICC` and save it in `pdfx` folder (or in `localtexmf` folder where tex can find it). A file name data base refreshing will be necessary.

As noted by **Enrico** there is a bug in `pdfx`. The command `\Subject` won't work. To counter this simply put (Thanks to Enrico):

```
\newcommand{\Subject}[1]{\gdef\xmpSubject{#1}}
```

before `\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}`

Comment: There is a bug in `pdfx.sty`: the `\Subject` command is not recognized in the XMP data file. It's sufficient to add `\newcommand{\Subject}[1]{\gdef\xmpSubject{#1}}` after `\usepackage[...]{pdfx}`

Comment: Looking at the `.sty` file one sees that `\xmpSubject` is initialized to `\xmpKeywords`, but the corresponding macro for setting `\xmpSubject` at runtime is missing. I'm inclined to consider this a bug, as `\Subject` is a documented interface.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. Please leave your comments here (I mean don't delete them). I will try to ping CVR.

Comment: Sorry, I will fix this and will get back as soon as possible. Many thanks for the time of all.

Comment: @CVRadhakrishnan: Thank you very much. `:-)`