# Adding metadata using pdfx fails

Tags: pdf, metadata, pdf-a, xmp, pdfx

I'd like to generate a PDF/A-compliant document. Thus I need to embed the metadata using XMP but somehow the following MWE doesn't work.

```
\RequirePackage{pdf14}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\newcommand{\Subject}[1]{\gdef\xmpSubject{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xmpdata}
\Subject{Foo}
\Title{My Sample Title} 
\Author{Me} 
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    Foobar
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this and what's up with packages like hyperxmp?

Comment: "does not work" is not an appropriate error message. What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Just move the `\newcommand{\Subject}{...}` line before `\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}`

Comment: Well, there isn't any error but the PDF doesn't contain any metadata afterwards. 
Moving the subject line or leaving out the subject at all  doesn't help either.

Comment: Do you have `ISOcoated_v2_300_bas.ICC` in your computer somewhere? See : [Add metadata in pdf as type pdf/a](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87913)

Answer (score 2):

Your provided example works fine for me. Therefore, I have to assume there is some confusion about the XMP Metadata and/or the process on how to typeset the document.

First of all, XMP metadata is *not* the PDF metadata, e.g. XMP data can be viewed by using Adobe Acrobat: File, Properties, Additional Metadata; whereas the normal metadata already shows up under file, properties.

Secondly: Do you use pdflatex to create your document?