# Validate PDF/A-2u with MathTime 2 Lite fonts

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, pdfx, pdf-a, mathtime

How might I get the following source, using the MathTime 2 Lite fonts, to pass PDF/A-2u validation? The error is: "The Font dictionary of all fonts shall define the map of all used character codes to Unicode values, either via a To Unicode entry …"

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}% load now to avoid \dddot, \ddddot clash with mtpro2

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{mtp2lite}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

Note that the `mtp2lite.sty` file used is the same as the file `mtpro2.sty`, included in the "mtplite" files from CTAN, with one necessary change made so as to avoid a "no room for new count" error. Namely, the line

```
\alloc@0\count\countdef\insc@unt\pointcount@
```

is replaced with:

```
\newcount\pointcount@
```

The PDF validator app veraPDF gives a validation failure report including the following:

```
 <validationReport profileName="PDF/A-2U validation profile" statement="PDF file is not compliant with Validation Profile requirements." isCompliant="false">
    <details passedRules="123" failedRules="1" passedChecks="8111" failedChecks="3">
      <rule specification="ISO 19005-2:2011" clause="6.2.11.7" testNumber="1" status="failed" passedChecks="0" failedChecks="3">
        <description>The Font dictionary of all fonts shall define the map of all used character codes to Unicode values, either via a ToUnicode entry,
        or other mechanisms as defined in ISO 19005-2, 6.2.11.7.2.</description>
        <object>Glyph</object>
        <test>toUnicode != null</test>
        <check status="failed">
          <context>root/document[0]/pages[1](20 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](21 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[104]/usedGlyphs[0](FFYPYY+MT2SYT 0 0  0)</context>
        </check>
        <check status="failed">
          <context>root/document[0]/pages[0](6 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](8 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[299]/usedGlyphs[0](OVWIGM+MT2MIT 25 0  0)</context>
        </check>
        <check status="failed">
          <context>root/document[0]/pages[0](6 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](8 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[248]/usedGlyphs[0](XIQLHG+MT2SYS 0 0  0)</context>
        </check>
      </rule>
    </details>
  </validationReport>
```

Comment: By far the most elegant solution is to cut the Gordian knot and use `unicode-math`. However, the `mmap` package has Unicode mappings for T1, TS1, OML, OMX and so on. I believe `newtxmath` and `newpxmath` also put some effort into making Unicode mappings work.

Comment: @Davislor: alas, I'm using MathTime 2 fonts - actually, MathTime Professional II fonts, not the "lite" version. Is it possible to use `unicode-math` and still do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the two following instructions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}% load now to avoid \dddot, \ddddot clash with mtpro2

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\pdfmapfile{=mtpro2.map}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}

\pdfglyphtounicode{EM}{0058 0058 0058 0058 0058 0058 0058 0058}
\pdfglyphtounicode{NUL}{0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060}

\begin{document}

\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

The numbers are made up, basically the one is a lot of X and the other of Z. But as math doesn't copy&paste anyway as most of the tounicode values are wrong, it should matter much what one use here.

Comment: I tried that, but still get error: "For all Type 1 font subsets referenced within a conforming file, the font descriptor dictionary shall include a CharSet string listing the character names defined in the font subset, as described in PDF Reference Table 5.18". The specific errors relate to TeXGyreHeros and TeXGyreTermsX.

Comment: the example validates for me.

Comment: valiadates with what app or site?

Comment: I used like you verapdf.

Comment: I missed the `\pdfmapfile{=mtpro2.map}` command; with that included, the pdf validates for me, too. It validates even with the full MathTime Professional II math fonts and just `\usepackage{mtpro2}`. But my actual, book-length, document, which uses `newtxtext` with `mtpro2` still won't validate against the same font descriptor dictionary criterion; I still get some errors regarding TeXGyreTermsX and TeXGyreHeros, even after I include `\pdfmapfile{=pdftex.map}`. I'll have to manufacture a new example shorter than my actual one.

Comment: I see two possible reasons for this: 1st `pdfx` is a complex package which can lead to unintended behaviour. [Try this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/535849/50129). 2nd your included graphics should be valid PDF/A-2u already.