# Plain footer goes over the edge with fancyhdr

Tags: margins, fancyhdr, pagestyle

I am using **fancydhr** for my title page to display logos on its header and footer.
For the rest of my report I use \pagestyle{plain} to get the standard footer with only the page number. But using the \pagestyle{fancy} on the first page causes the entire document to be like shifted down, and the page numbering disappears. I can only recover it by increasing the bottom margin up to 6 cm but it keeps a 6 cm space between the end of the text and the end of the page, so this solution does not suit me well.

Here is my code with my desired margins :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, includehead, includefoot, heightrounded, footskip=30pt, headheight=12pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}

\setlength{\parindent}{4ex} % alinea size
\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=1 1 1, urlbordercolor=1 1 1}


% ============================  Header with logo ===============================

% -----------------------------------
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % supprime la ligne de header
\fancyhf{}
% ------------- Header --------------
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-a}}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-b}}
\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-c}}
% ------------- Footer --------------
\fancyfoot[L]{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{example-image-b}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{example-image-b}}
% -----------------------------------
\pagestyle{plain}

% ==============================================================================
% ================================= DOCUMENT ===================================
% ==============================================================================
\begin{document}

% Title Page
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\vspace*{3cm}   
\begin{center}
        \Huge \textsc{Rapport de stage}\\
    \vspace{10mm}
    \large \textit{présenté par}\\
    \vspace{5mm}
    \Large \textbf{Anderson DA SILVA} \\
    \vspace{7mm}
        \hrulefill \\ 
        \vspace{0,5cm}
            \Huge \textbf{Étude de la couche limite atmosphérique en Atlantique tropical dans le cadre de la campagne EUREC$^4$A}\\ 
        \hrulefill \\
    \vspace{10mm}

    \large Stage effectué au LATMOS du \textit{19 avril 2021} au \textit{19 juillet 2021}.\\
    Sous la direction et la tutelle de \textbf{Richard WILSON} et de \textbf{Hugo BELLENGER}.\\ \vspace{1cm}
\newpage

\end{center}

% -------------- Document corps ----------------
\lipsum[1-24]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't you get an error message when you compile? I get the message that \hypersetup{linkbordercolor=1 1 1, urlbordercolor=1 1 1} is an undefined control sequence. Disactivating this line for me makes the file compilable (except for not having your images).

Comment: When I add \usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref} (found on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498987/generate-pdf-a-1b-with-lualatex/535849#535849) the error message disappears. Please adapt your file by inserting example logos and have a look whether the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.log` file says you have to increase `\headheight` and `\footskip`. Do this by including `headheight=...,footskip=...` in the `geometry` line. Use the numbers as given in the warnings (or rounded up).

And good advice: always check the `.log` file

**Edit** :
Then, for the rest of the document with no header, set a newgeometry with `\newgeometry{left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, includefoot, heightrounded, footskip=30pt}` for example.

Comment: I've added the example images, and modified the ```geometry``` package options but nothing really changed. I've tried different lengths for ```footskip``` and ```headheight``` but it only acts like changing the bottom margin.

Comment: The `.log` file says `headheight` should be at least `57.42738pt` and `footskip` at least `100.11116pt`. You didn't do that.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I didn't read the right values in the ```.log```.
But what about the blank space on every pages that seems to be kept in case I would like to draw my header and footer on them ? I want the text to begin at the distance decided by the top margin, and to end at the distance told by the bottom margin

Comment: You can put at the beginning of the next page, after the `\newpage`, which by the way should be AFTER the `\end{center}`: `\newgeometry{includeheadfoot, headheight=12pt, footskip=30pt}`

Comment: And if you don't know where the next page begins, for example if the text continues at the page break: `\usepackage{afterpage}` ... 
`\afterpage{\globaldefs=1 \newgeometry{includeheadfoot, headheight=12pt, footskip=30pt}}` before `\begin{document}`

Comment: For a single page, one could use tikz and possibly tikzpagenodes {overlay, remember picture].

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a different approach: the images at top and bottom aren't really headers and footers.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage[
  left=2.5cm,
  right=2.5cm,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  includehead,
  includefoot,
  heightrounded,
  footskip=30pt,
  headheight=14pt
]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}

\setlength{\parindent}{4ex} % alinea size
\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=1 1 1, urlbordercolor=1 1 1}

\newcommand{\headimage}[2][]{%
  \raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\footimage}[2][]{%
  \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  }%
}

\pagestyle{plain}

% ==============================================================================
% ================================= DOCUMENT ===================================
% ==============================================================================
\begin{document}

% Title Page
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}

\vspace*{-2cm} % adjust to suit

\headimage[width=2.5cm]{example-image-a}\hfill
\headimage[width=2.5cm]{example-image-b}\hfill
\headimage[width=2.5cm]{example-image-c}

\vspace*{\stretch{1}}

{\Huge\scshape Rapport de stage\\}

{\large\itshape présenté par\\}

{\Large\bfseries Anderson DA SILVA\\}

\hrulefill \\ 

\vspace{0,5cm}

{\Huge\bfseries Étude de la couche limite atmosphérique en Atlantique 
  tropical dans le cadre de la campagne EUREC$^4$A\\}

\vspace{0,5cm}

\hrulefill \\

\vspace{10mm}

{\large Stage effectué au LATMOS du \textit{19 avril 2021} au \textit{19 juillet 2021}.\\
  Sous la direction et la tutelle de \textbf{Richard WILSON} et de \textbf{Hugo BELLENGER}.\\}

\vspace*{\stretch{2}}

\footimage[width=4.5cm]{example-image-b}\hfill
\footimage[width=4.5cm]{example-image-b}

\vspace*{-1cm} % adjust to suit

\end{center}

\clearpage
% -------------- Document corps ----------------
\lipsum[1-24]

\end{document}
```

Adjust the spacings to suit.

[image]

Comment: This was my old setup, and for sure it works !